# Formatting Json for Python LocustIO

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, locust

Why am I getting bad request for this post calls? It has to do with json formatting. How do I reformat the json object passed as param? I'm running a load test using LocustIO and Python.

```
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task
from slumber import API 
import json, requests

nameInquiry = """
[{
  "data": {
    "Account Number": "1234567898",
    "Bank Code": "EBN",
    "AppId": "com.appzonegroup.zone",
    "deviceId": "a4a7427032c286e3",
    "Sender Phone Number": "+2348094399450",
    "Sender Conversation ID": "161503479186618e8726fc4-70c0-4768-a2ea-5217c3a3c26d",
    "FileId": ""
  },
  "instruction": {
    "FunctionId": "",
    "FlowId": "813dac4f-7e44-4873-b45f-f6f3b5dbe436",
    "InstitutionCode": "",
    "TimeOutSeconds": 30
  }
}]
"""
myheaders = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}


class NameInquiries(TaskSet):
  @task(1)
  def send(self):
    response = self.client.post("/zoneflowsapi/api/Goto/goto/", data=json.dumps(nameInquiry), headers= myheaders )

    print("Response status code:", response.status_code)
    print("Response content:", response.text)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html#json.dumps) takes as input json object (lists & dictionaries) and serializes it giving a string as output. You are feeding it with `nameInquiry`, which is already a string by itself, thus the error.

Furthermore [post](https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/api.html#locust.clients.HttpSession.post) gets a dictionary as input, so there is no need to serialize it. The simple solution is to set `nameInquiry` as a json object (notice the missing `"""` below) and feed it directly to post.

```
nameInquiry = [{
    "data": {
    "Account Number": "1234567898",
    "Bank Code": "EBN",
    "AppId": "com.appzonegroup.zone",
    ...
}]

...

response = self.client.post("/zoneflowsapi/api/Goto/goto/", data=nameInquiry, headers=myheaders)
```

Otherwise you can keep the string and deserialize it using [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html#json.loads):

```
nameInquiry = json.loads("""
[{
  "data": {
  "Account Number": "1234567898",...
""")
```

Comment: Thanks. saved my day.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, I used above method but still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

There are two general ways to POST JSON data with Locust. I prefer to pass a dictionary to `self.client.post` [using the json keyword argument](https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/api.html#locust.clients.HttpSession.post) because I don't have to worry about creating valid JSON:

```
nameInquiry = [{
  "data": {
    "Account Number": "1234567898",
    "Bank Code": "EBN",
    "AppId": "com.appzonegroup.zone",
    "deviceId": "a4a7427032c286e3",
    "Sender Phone Number": "+2348094399450",
    "Sender Conversation ID": "161503479186618e8726fc4-70c0-4768-a2ea-5217c3a3c26d",
    "FileId": ""
  },
  ...
}]

response = self.client.post("/zoneflowsapi/api/Goto/goto/", json=nameInquiry)
```

The other approach is to manually create a valid JSON string, or use `json.dumps(dict)` to create a valid JSON string, and pass the string to `self.client.post` using the `data` argument:

```
nameInquiryString = """
[{
  "data": {
    "Account Number": "1234567898",
    "Bank Code": "EBN",
    "AppId": "com.appzonegroup.zone",
    "deviceId": "a4a7427032c286e3",
    "Sender Phone Number": "+2348094399450",
    "Sender Conversation ID": "161503479186618e8726fc4-70c0-4768-a2ea-5217c3a3c26d",
    "FileId": ""
  }
...
}]
"""    
response = self.client.post("/zoneflowsapi/api/Goto/goto/", data=nameInquiryString)
```

If you are using `self.client.put`, you must use the second approach, because the `put` method does not support the `json` keyword argument.